# How to pass parameter to callback in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to pass some parameter in call back like the following example. Is it a possible? Or I need to do it in another way?

```
function testCallback(callback, destination){
    // how can I pass the destination to callback
    callLib(callback)
}

function myCallback(destination){
    //do something
}
```

callLib is an external library that accept. I guess the interface should be like this

```
function callLib(callback){
    callback("something")
}
```

this one I think is not duplicate one. Sorry for my bad english. I have already change the question. see if you understand what the problem is

Comment: What is `callLib`?

Comment: _"Is it a possible?"_ ? Have you tried it ? What did not work ?

Comment: Should it not be `callback(destination)` supposing you passed `myCallback` to `testCallback`

Comment: callLib is an external library that I can only pass a callback with one parameter

Comment: This one is not duplicate to the above. May be it is my enlist mistake

Answer (score 0):

I played with callbacks all day to learn how to do this.  Here is some example code:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554672/jqueryui-dialog-doesnt-stop-code-to-wait-for-user-input/37556573#37556573